# how to obtain facebook credentials in iphone app when using face.com API

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, image-recognition

I am trying to make a sample iPhone app that can use the faces.recognize API call.  I can successfully connect to the Face.com API using RestKit, however, I have no idea how to obtain the user id, session, etc.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

I think reading the documentation properly would have helped more. I found a related in just 5 minutes of research at [Face.com](http://developers.face.com/docs/) . There are a list of methods there and the realted sample responses. What you need is, I think, this URL:

http://developers.face.com/docs/api/account-users/

Comment: What you need is not to pollute other peoples' questions with useless answers.  If you don't know anything about face.com then don't bother answering.

Comment: @gonzobrains Oh! thanks, for the great comment. I will keep that in mind ;) By the way if you have got the answer please post it, so that useless people like us can learn something and become useful :) :P

Answer (score 0):

Getting the userID, session, etc. is actually a part of the Facebook API (not face.com) and some info about it can be found here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/

Comment: Hi, Dan.  Yes, I realize that.  I was hoping to find an answer explaining how to put it all together (i.e., connecting the Facebook API together with Face.com's API).